# How do I change the angle of a face by entering a number in edit mode?

Tags: 3d-view

I want two faces of an object to be at the same angle.
To do this, I thought I could get the angle of one face and adjust the other face to that angle.
However, I can't find anything like that in the property shelf or sidebar.
How can I achieve this?
Or is there another way to align the angles of the two faces?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could select the face, in the *Transform Orientations* panel create a new custom orientation and keep it selected:

[image]

Then select the other face and press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and this face will align with the first one:

[image]

In *Object* mode, if you want to align an object to a custom orientation, first select the face and create the orientation:

[image]

Then select the other object and *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation*:

[image]

Comment: i still remember you gave me that answer....maybe a year or more ago ;)

Comment: I'm not sure it answers his question though  ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
In my environment, when I press Shift + S, I get this pie menu. If I press 0, nothing happens.
I'm using Blender version 3.2, is there a different keyboard shortcut?
I tried to figure it out myself, but I couldn't.

Comment: hello, sorry i probably meant SZ0

Comment: Thank you very much.
I was able to align the faces to any orientation.
However, this changes the shape of the face when it is oriented.
I have added an image to this post.
Now I want to match the round face to the orientation of the currently selected face.
If I continue to select the round face and press SZ0, the orientation of the face will be aligned, but the round face will no longer be a perfect circle.
Is there any way to align the orientation of the faces without changing their shape at all?

Sorry for asking so many times.

Comment: in Object mode it would be possible to align an object with an axis and it wouldn't change its shape, in Edit mode I can't think of any solution but I may miss something...

Comment: Thank you.
I have added an image of how it looks when done in object mode.
I tried pressing SZ0 after putting it in object mode, but it still changes the shape.
The origin is set to the center of the object, is there anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: In Object mode you need to use another method, I've edited my answer

Comment: Sorry, my reading comprehension was not good enough.
I was able to align the orientation of the faces without changing the shape using the method you taught me.
Thank you kindly for your kind words.